# Citation alias with multibib and natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, subdividing, multibib

I need a bibliography that presents citation as (Surname, year), for which I am using `natbib`, and that allows two different bibliographies at the end of the document, for which I am using `multibib`.

Point is: I'd like to use the "alias" command of natbib for the secondary bibliography, but it doesn't work. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{sec}{Other bibliographic references}
\defcitealias{intlog}{International journal of logistics, issue 91}

\begin{document}

Something something something and then \citetalias{intlog}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

with a proper entry in the file `bibliography.bib`.

How to make the command `citetalias{intlog}` work in the secondary bibliography?

What do I know:

- `\citetaliassec{intlog}` doesn't work
- `\defcitetaliassec{intlog}` doesn't work as well (ok, that was a long shot)

that makes me think the alias system is not compatible with multibib...

Of course whatever other solution different from the alias system is absolutely welcomed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Of course whatever other solution different from the alias system is
>   absolutely welcomed.

As often I recommend `biblatex`. However the solution below doesn't use `biblatex`.

---

Your example has some errors listed below.

*Errors related to `multibib`*

- If you define a new bibliography with `\newcites{<ext>}{<headind>}`, the new commands `\bibliographystyle<ext>`, `\bibliography<ext>` and `\cite<ext>` will be defined. So in your case the line

  ```
  \newcites{sec}{Other bibliographic references}
  ```

  leads to the commands:

  ```
  \bibliographystylesec
  \bibliographysec
  ```

  and a new file `<ext>.aux` will be created. This new file needs his own bibtex run.

*Errors related to your bibliography style `plainnat`*

- your style writes the following lines to your included `bbl` file (included by `\bibliography`).

  ```
  \newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{}
  \newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1}
  \newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}
  \newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}
  ```

  You want to have two bibliographies and so the definition of the commands are done twice. This occurs to the error that the commands are defined. **One** approach would be to set the commands undefined before including the second bibliography.

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{xampl}

  \let\noopsort\undefined
  \let\printfirst\undefined
  \let\singleletter\undefined
  \let\switchargs\undefined

  \bibliographystylesec{plainnat}
  \bibliographysec{xampl}
  ```
- the style `plainnat` is a numerical citation style. The manual of `natbib` provides the following information

  > By default, natbib is in author–year mode. This can be changed by
  >
  > 1. selecting a numerical bibliography style with predefined citation style, defined either in the package or in the local configuration
  >      file;

*Errors related to `natbib`'s `\defcitealias`*

- the command `\defcitealias` is described in the documentation with the following sentence:

  > Sometimes one wants to refer to a reference with a special
  >   designation, rather than by the authors
- that means your key of `\defcitealias` must be a given entry of you bib file. You doesn't show us your bib file so I used the file `xampl.bib` which is located in your texmf tree.
- the command `\defcitealias` makes no differences between the different bibliographies, so you can use it as described in the documentation.
- `multibib` defines the command `\citep<ext>` etc. The defined commands are all listed in the command `\@mb@citenamelist`. In the documentation of `multibib` you find the following hint:

  > Packages which define new cite commands can add these commands using
  >   `\@mb@citenamelist`. The default definition, which already includes
  >   natbib’s cite variants, is given below.
  >
  > ```
  > \def\@mb@citenamelist{cite,citep,citet,citealp,citealt}
  > ```
- You see the commands `citepalias` and `citetalias` are missed. So before the package `multibib` is loaded add the following lines:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \def\@mb@citenamelist{cite,citep,citet,citealp,citealt,citepalias,citetalias}
  \makeatother
  ```

---

Based on the given information here the result as a minimal example with the resulting output. The compilation steps are done by the great tool arara:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex : { files :[test , sec] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
%: Start Header
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\def\@mb@citenamelist{cite,citep,citet,citealp,citealt,citepalias,citetalias}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{sec}{Other bibliographic references}

\defcitealias{manual-full}{International journal of logistics, issue 91}

\begin{document}

\cite{article-full}

\citesec{booklet-full}

Something something something and then \citepaliassec{manual-full}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xampl}

\let\noopsort\undefined
\let\printfirst\undefined
\let\singleletter\undefined
\let\switchargs\undefined

\bibliographystylesec{plainnat}
\bibliographysec{xampl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see I made some avoidable mistakes in the MWE, and I apologize for that. I've started to think I should begin to use `biblatex`, but right now I simply don't have time to dig in it (but with all the time wasted for this and other issues... who knows?)

As regards the issue:
I followed your exhaustive suggestions and got the aliased citation to appear correctly in the secondary bibliography.

Unfortunately, it still appears in the primary bibligraphy :D Is this because I am not compiling with `arara`? (I deleted the `aux` files)

Comment: @scannerdarkly: arara is only a tool I ran pdfaltex, bibtex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex. So there is something else odd.

Comment: OK I don't exactly know what but I moved the four `\let` commands before calling the first bibliography and it works;

strange thing is, I moved them back, and it still works.... so probably it's something else (but don't know what, I run everything the correct number of times). I'm lost, but it's absolutely not a problem right now!thanks!