# Reference twice in revtex using two .bib files with natbib package

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, natbib, revtex, multiple-citations

With the current code the document gives the same reference twice.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers,comma,sort&compress,super}{natbib} 
\documentclass[aps,prl, twocolumn, a4paper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{multibib}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib1}

\bibliographystylerec{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the exact problem? Your code gives no citations and no bib entries so it's hard to be clear what you're seeing and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please, have a look to: [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66834/106162) covers the `multibib`/`natbib` issues which there are a few of, but `revtex` appears to be causing further issues.